# How should I upload the source files of my paper?

Tags: publications, journals

My paper has just been accepted.
The journal needs me to complete a final submission.

> 1. A LaTeX or Microsoft Word application file. This should include
>    keywords/index terms, and bios and photos if you are including them.
>    The contents of this file should match the accepted PDF.  Failure to
>    submit a source file may result in publishing delays.
> 2. If your figures are not embedded in the source file of your
>    manuscript, you will also need to upload separate figure files. The
>    acceptable formats are Word, eps, ps, tiff, ppt and excel. We do NOT
>    accept png or jpeg files for figures.

How do I upload the LaTeX file mentioned above?

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{figures/func.eps}
    \caption{side-channel exploitation.}
    \label{Victim function}
\end{figure}
```

My images are all placed in the figures folder. In the Latex source file, I use the command above to quote. But I didn't understand the meaning of journal.
What does the following sentence mean?

> If your figures are not embedded in the source file of your
> manuscript, you will also need to upload separate figure files.

Can I upload the entire folder, including Latex files, picture directories, and bbl files? Or upload Latex files, upload the images one by one. Many pictures are used in the paper. Additional info: the optional file description has no bib.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congratulations on the acceptance of your paper.

Your figures are *not* embedded in the source, they are *referenced* (by name and path) in the source, so they should be uploaded separately. However, you should almost certainly make some changes first!

1. Journals have their own file structure. They usually don't want to be using your file structure as a subset of their own! That means that you should adjust the path references in the LaTeX files so that they **avoid the sub-directory called `figs`**. Shift everything to the same, flat level; check that it all compiles correctly with all the figures and source documents in the same directory, and only then upload it.
2. Upload the figures, bib files, and other material one file at a time. Most journals hate zipped source material. If the journal does not accept `bib` files (check with them if you can!), then you will probably have to paste the `bbl` file into your original document. If your are unsure how to do this, I suggest that you either check with the journal editors, or ask at the [TeX forum on StackExchange,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/biblatex-submitting-to-a-journal)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. But the optional file description has no bib. 
I uploaded the picture in the original answer.

Comment: I have added an extra line about `bib` and `bbl` files. The TeX forum or the journal itself will give you good advice. ... Don't panic!

Comment: Really Thanks!!!

Comment: I think this description is too strict. I have always kept my own directory structure and just uploaded a .tar.gz file of the whole source directory -- and that has always worked. The people who do production are experienced and skilled, they can deal with subdirectories.